# IIS doDynamicCompression and Browser Fallback

Tags: iis, compression

I want to enable GZip compression on my controller actions using IIS's doDynamicCompression configuration option.

The question is what will happen if one of my users uses a browsers that doesnt support GZip - would IIS detect it and send it uncompressed?

Answer (score 0):

When your users send request to the serveur, the Browser send a header Accept-Encoding.
This header specifies to the server with compresssions methods are accepted by the Browser.
For exemple "deflate,gzip", "gzip" or nothing.

IIS parses this Header to compress or not the response.